# How to dynamically play JavaFX animations

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I have a Java application where, when I click a button, an ImageView moves a certain amount across the screen. How can I make it so that every time I click the button, an animation is run? I know how to make a click button and have it run a function. I just don't know how to use animations properly to dynamically run new animations.

```
public Timeline moveAnimation(double x, double y) {
    // horizontal movement
    KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(turtle.xProperty(), x);
    KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), kv);
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);

    // vertical movement
    KeyValue kv2 = new KeyValue(turtle.yProperty(), y);
    KeyFrame kf2 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), kv2);
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf2);

    return timeline;
}

public void move(double x, double y) {
    moveAnimation(x, y).play();
}
```

The above method will play once. When I try to run the move() method again with new values, nothing happens.

Comment: Get the Timeline object and run timeline.play() again - doe's that do the trick?

Comment: Yes. It works!!! Wow I completely missed something because I had tried that before, but I probably had some bug in it. It works now that I've tried it again. Thank you.

Comment: I posted a complete answer with an actual code snippet etc. If I was helpful, I'd love it if you could accept my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Timeline`holds all of the animation "steps" (AKA: `KeyFrame`).

in the `move` method, you should assign a variable of type `Timeline` with the returned value from the `moveAnimation` method, like this:

```
public void move(double x, double y) {
     Timeline timeline = moveAnimation(x, y).play();
     //use timeline wherever...
}
```

And then call `timeline.play()` when you want to reuse the animation.

Good luck!